# When try to display an image, the error “404 not found” appears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angular, paperclip

I use Rails Api 5.1.6 as a backend. As a client, I use Angular 4. All data is stored in an Oracle database. Images in the database are stored in the format "Blob". I also use the paperclip gem to work with images on Rails Api.

So when I try to display an image on the client, the error "[404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI9sa.png)" appears. Here is the error in the console:

> GET http://localhost:4200/photos/original/missing.png 404 (Not Found)

I also tried to follow this link:

> http://localhost:3000/photos/original/missing.png

But such an error occurs (If you need, I can add a complete error here):

> "#ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET]
>   "/photos/original/missing.png""

JSON:

```
[
{
l_users_id: 65,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1357,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1358,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 51,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 2,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1360,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 0,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1372,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1371,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1370,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
},
{
l_users_id: 1373,
photo: "/photos/original/missing.png"
}
]
```

photos_controller.rb:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @photos = Photo.all

    array = @photos.map do |photo|
        photo_push = {
            l_users_id:      photo.l_users_id,
            photo:           photo.photo.url
        }

        photo_push
    end

    render json: array
  end

    def show
        @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
        photo_hash = {
            l_users_id:      photo.l_users_id,
            photo:           photo.photo.url
        }

        render json: photo_hash
    end

end
```

photo.rb:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "l_users_id"

  has_attached_file :photo

  validates_attachment_presence :photo
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

end
```

Comment: I already tried to change the URL from this `"/photos/original/missing.png"` to this `"/photo/original/missing.png"`

Comment: in localhost 3000 it takes it as a route... uses full path   http://localhost:3000/public/photos/original/missing.png

Comment: @RamAnji did not help, I have this folder empty

Comment: then where are store ur images...check the photos folder either it have the images or not?

Comment: @RamAnji images stored  the database or do they need to be extracted from there

Answer (score 0):

`src="http://localhost:8080/images/missing.png"`

move that to the `public/images` folder